# Can't manage to get nginx rewrite rule working

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, return

I need to create some rewrite (maybe return?) rules...

I need to redirect:

`www.domain1.es/es` to `www.domain1.es`

`www.domain1.es/en` to `www.domain2.eu/en`

`www.domain1.es/fr` to `www.domain2.eu/fr`

Also need:

`www.domain2.eu/es` to `www.domain1.es`

I'll appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `en` and `fr` redirects are easily achieved with a `return` directive. In the `server` block for the `www.domain1.es` domain, you could try:

```
location ^~ /en { return 301 $scheme://www.domain2.eu$request_uri; }
location ^~ /fr { return 301 $scheme://www.domain2.eu$request_uri; }
```

Notice the `^~` modifier which make this *prefix location* take precedence over any regex location at the same level. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Removing the `/es` prefix from the URI will require a rewrite. You could try these:

In the `server` block for the `www.domain1.es` domain:

```
rewrite ^/es(.*)$ $1 permanent;
```

In the `server` block for the `www.domain2.eu` domain:

```
rewrite ^/es(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain1.es$1 permanent;
```

Either of the above could be placed inside a `location ^~ /es` block to improve efficiency (but I do not think it is necessary). Also, the latter does not need to remove the `/es` prefix (as it is done at the other server anyway).

Comment: Thank you very much!

First part worked!

`rewrite ^/es(.*)$ $1 permanent;` made a loop redirect, but it is a Prestashop issue that I should fix by code.